# How to check zlib version in file apk was builded

Tags: android, c++, apk, zlib

I have an apk file. I want to check its zlib version. The solution to including parameters in the manifest is not possible because the superior requests it. I have searched a lot of the apk tools including the company's toolbox but it is useless.

Comment: I hope to get your feedback soon!

Comment: apk files are zip files.  Rename it and use a zip tool(s) of your choice to check the archive format/version.  Don't have such a tool to-hand so unable to give you a definitive answer.

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: I have a request on this issue :((, Thanks for answers

Answer (score 2):

An [apk file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_application_package) is a zip file. Zip files contain no information about what code or what version of that code was used for the deflate compression. Deflate compressed data is a fixed format that is compatible with all compliant inflators, and so there is no need for any compressor version information.

Comment: Can I use the command line to extract the information it contains? Thanks for answer!

Comment: If you're asking if you can extract the contents from the command line, then yes. Find or get an unzip utility for that purpose. It's already there if you're using Linux or macOS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to ask a little more, is it possible to extract the version zlib information on Window? I want to check again before I do!

Comment: No. Not on Windows. Not anywhere. The zlib version is not in the zip file. Not there. Can't get it. No. No. No.

Comment: You're really funny :D

Answer (score 0):

Zlib is a native shared library that is used in devices, so there isn't any Zlib in your apk and you should the Zlib version on android releases, for example in android 12 I think the Zlib version is 1.2.12